# ¿como evitar registros duplicados en un mismo mes al importar un excel en laravel,

Tags: php, laravel, excel

Buen dia, Estoy realizando una Importación de un archivo excel, con la librería laravelexcel, quisiera saber como impedir registros duplicados al importar el archivo, que al detectar  el campo "numero de contenedor!, si ya fue registrado en el mes no se guarde, pero si hay otros , pero si es otro mes y no ha sido importado si se guarde.

```
 use SkipsErrors;
    public function rules(): array
    {
 return [

        'container_number' => Rule::exists('import_opercont','ImportnNumContenedor')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('ImportnNumContenedor','=' ,['container_number'])
            //->whereIn('ImportnNumContenedor',['container_number'])
            ->whereMonth('created_at', '=', date('m'));
        })
        ];
    }

 public function customValidationMessages()
    {
        return [
            'container_number.exists' => 'Contenedor ya registrado en el mes actual.',
               ];
    }
```

Comment: Puedes solucionarlo, agregando una llave de tipo UNIQUE a tu columna ImportnNumContenedor

Comment: Funciono, gracias.